# react page gtihub deployment of a web page

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router-dom, github-pages

while hosting react web page on GitHub pages it shows only white pages even though I used the instruction  on the deployment of react page on Github.
I think it is due to the react-router-dom (Switch and route ) methods I used to redirect to its page. please give me a solution regarding this.

I tried to edit the package.json file but it not be solved and I also tried to push the file again to that repo branch

Comment: can you add more informations .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.